# Server-side Outlook.Exchange Rule The Executes a Script

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, server-side

I'd like to create a server-side rule in Exchange that runs a script. It's fairly straightforward:

- Detect an email from a certain sender and subject line
- Kick off a script to process the attachment

I've done this before using client-side rules, but this is not an attended mailbox, so no one will have an Outlook client open. That's a poor way to run a production process anyway. Can anyone provide some guidance as to how to go about it? Perhaps there is another way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Server side rules do not run any scripts. That would be a security vulnerability. The bets you can get is copy/move/send message.

You would need to create a standalone app or a service that connects to the mailbox periodically (OOM? EWS?) and does what you need it to do.

Comment: Thanks. What's OOM/EWS?

Comment: Outlook Object Model and Exchange Web Services.